# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comment_theme()

Tags: php, comments, blog, cms

I have this wordpress site build up. In the blog section my post is getting repeated which I do not want how can I get rid of this situation

Use this link: http://rymahrice.com/some-energy-drinks-contain-too-much-caffeine-for-kids/

scroll down and you will notice the error and the whole post being repeated.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
/*
    The template for displaying Comments.
*/
?>
<?php 
function comment_theme($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
    <li <?php comment_class("clearfix"); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
        <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment_wrap">
            <div class="gravatar">
                <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='60',$default=''); ?>
                <time class="comment_time"><?php echo get_comment_date(); ?></time>
            </div>
            <div class='comment_content'>
                <div class="comment_meta">
                    <h4><?php printf( '<cite class="comment_author">%s</cite>', get_comment_author_link()) ?></h4>

                </div>
                <div class='comment_text'>
                    <?php comment_text() ?>
                    <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
                    <span class="unapproved"><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'fringe_tech') ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)', 'fringe_tech' ),'  ','') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>

<div id="comments">
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
    <p class="nopassword"><?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'fringe_tech' ); ?></p>
</div>
<?php   return;
    endif;
?>

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h3 id="comments-title"><?php
    printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number(), 'fringe_tech' ),
    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' );
    ?></h3>

<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older Comments', 'fringe_tech' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'fringe_tech' ) ); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="contents">
    <ol class="commentlist">
        <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'comment_theme' ) ); ?>
    </ol>
</div>
<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older Comments', 'fringe_tech' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'fringe_tech' ) ); ?></div>
            </div><!-- .navigation -->
<?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

<?php else :
    if ( ! comments_open() ) :
?>
    </div>
<?php endif; // end ! comments_open() ?>

<?php endif; // end have_comments() ?>


<?php if ( comments_open() ) { ?>

    <div id="respond">

        <h3><?php comment_form_title( __( 'Leave a Reply', 'fringe_tech' ), __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'fringe_tech' ) ); ?></h3>

        <div class="cancel-comment-reply">
            <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
        </div>

        <?php 
        if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            printf( __('<p style="clear:both;">You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p></div>', 'fringe_tech' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink()) );
        } else { 
        ?>

            <form action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-comments-post.php' ); ?>" method="post" id="sendform">

                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

                <div class="logged_out">
                    <?php printf( __('Logged in as <a href="%1$s/wp-admin/profile.php">%2$s</a>.', 'fringe_tech' ), get_option('siteurl'), $user_identity ); ?> <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php esc_html_e('Log out of this account', 'fringe_tech'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Log out &raquo;', 'fringe_tech'); ?></a>
                </div>

                <?php  } else { ?>

                <span class="comment_element">

                    <span class="comment_input">

                        <input type="text" name="author" class="input" id="author" value="<?php if($comment_author != "") { echo $comment_author; } else { echo "Name *"; } ?>" size="22" tabindex="1"  />

                    </span>

                    <span class="comment_label">

                        <small><?php if ($req) esc_html_e('* required', 'fringe_tech'); ?></small>

                    </span>

                </span>

                <span class="comment_element">

                    <span class="comment_input">

                        <input type="text" name="email" class="input" id="email" value="<?php if($comment_author_email != "") { echo $comment_author_email; } else { echo "Email *"; } ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" />

                    </span>

                    <span class="comment_label">

                        <small><?php esc_html_e('(will not be published)', 'fringe_tech'); ?> <?php if ($req) esc_html_e('* required', 'fringe_tech'); ?></small>

                    </span>

                </span>

                <span class="comment_element">

                    <span class="comment_input">

                        <input type="text" name="url" class="input" id="url" value="<?php if($comment_author_url != "") { echo $comment_author_url; } else { echo "Web Site"; } ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" />       

                    </span>

                </span>

                <?php } ?>

                <span class="comment_element">

                    <span class="comment_textarea">

                        <textarea class="textarea" name="comment" id="comment" cols="70" rows="10" tabindex="4"><?php esc_html_e('Message *', 'fringe_tech'); ?></textarea>

                    </span>

                </span>

                <div class="comment_element">

                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <h6>
                            <span class="small_buttons <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>send_comment<?php } else { ?>send_comment_admin<?php } ?>">
                                <span class="<?php echo get_option("button_colors", "ocean"); ?>_l small_left"><span class="<?php echo get_option("button_colors", "ocean"); ?>_r small_right"><?php echo get_option("button_post_comment", "Post Comment"); ?></span></span>
                            </span>
                        </h6>
                    </div>

                    <span class="comment_message"></div>
                    <p><?php comment_id_fields(); ?></p>

                </div>

                <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

            </form>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, we can only guess: you included some file twice, and in that file is a function declaration.

Comment: Actually its framework should I send you the comment.php code

Comment: No, you should add the code *to your question*.

Answer (score 1):

Your `comments.php` is included multiple times for some reason. Look for `comments_template()` – maybe it is called too early.

Each time that happens, PHP tries to create the function `comment_theme()` again. This cannot work, function names must be unique.

Move the function declaration to the `functions.php`. So everything including …

```
<?php 
function comment_theme($comment, $args, $depth) {
    // functions body   
}
?>
```

… goes to the `functions.php`, and the `comments.php` starts with:

```
<?php
/*
    The template for displaying Comments.
*/
?>
<div id="comments">
```

Comment: but if the comment section is under loop and then is it repeating the picture title and content too

Comment: @KennEthel Somewhere you are including a file too early or multiple times. Maybe in your main loop. Impossible to tell with that code.

Comment: Ok let me check